# Connect to Heroku Node.js server from Java desktop client

Tags: java, node.js, heroku, socket.io, libgdx

I have created a simple game that uses Java, Socket.IO, and a NodeJS server. This game works perfectly when hosted on my local machine.

**I am having trouble connecting to the server from the Java game client when it's hosted on heroku .**

Does Heroku block connections from desktop clients?

Any help is very much appreciated :)

Java game client connection

```
public void connectSocket(){

    try{
        socket = IO.socket("https://galaga1v1.herokuapp.com/");
        socket.connect();

    }catch (Exception e){

        System.out.println(e);
    }

}
```

The server is running

Heroku logs

```
2016-08-06T20:27:28.433806+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2016-08-06T20:27:29.471418+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2016-08-06T20:27:31.181351+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2016-08-06T20:27:31.131273+00:00 app[web.1]: Server is now running...
```

Server code

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var players = [];

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, function(){

console.log("Server is now running..." + String(process.env.PORT) );

});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
console.log("Player Connected!");
socket.emit('socketID', { id: socket.id });
socket.emit('getPlayers', players);
socket.broadcast.emit('newPlayer', {id: socket.id});
socket.on('playerMoved', function(data){
    data.id = socket.id;
    socket.broadcast.emit('playerMoved', data);

    for(var i = 0; i < players.length; i++){

        if(players[i].id == data.id){
            players[i].x = data.x;
        }

    }
});

socket.on('playerShoot', function(data){
    data.id = socket.id;
    socket.broadcast.emit('playerShoot', data);

});

socket.on('playerHit',function(data){

    data.id = socket.id;
    socket.broadcast.emit('playerHit', data);
    console.log("player has been hit");


});

socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log("Player Disconnected!");
    socket.broadcast.emit('playerDisconnected', {id: socket.id });
    for(var i = 0; i < players.length; i++){
        if(players[i].id == socket.id){
            players.splice(i,1);
        }
    }
});
players.push(new player(socket.id, 0));
});

function player(id, x){

this.x = x;
this.id = id;

}
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: My game client isn't communicating with the server, but the server is running.

Comment: Does it give an error or anything? Or fail silently? What exactly is going on?

Comment: I guess it's failing silently. My game client normally has a socket connection with the server and they communicate back and forth sending data. But now the server doesn't seem to be receiving anything from the game client. (This works perfectly when hosted on localhost)

Comment: I suggest putting some logging statements around the `socket.connect()` call to find out the status of the connection (if there is no exception)

Comment: Thanks! I got it working. Turns out that I just needed to rebuild my project in android studio... The code was fine, just not compiling I guess.